# How to report bugs and issues to the wireguard team?

Tags: vpn, bugs

I think I have spotted a major bug in the Wireguard app for Android but I can't see any reliable way to report it (and the IRC channel is probably not the best place to report bugs).

Does anyone know a reliable channel to report possible WG bugs?

Comment: If you are referring to: [WireGuard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wireguard.android) and the reviewed Android To Do list: https://www.wireguard.com/todo/#android-app I would still go through the IRC channel as others can vet the 'bug' to make sure it isn't user/configuration error.

Answer (score 0):

For core Wireguard bugs, you should use the mailing list :
https://lists.zx2c4.com/mailman/listinfo/wireguard

If it has security implication, you should rather send a mail at `security@wireguard.com`.

https://www.wireguard.com/#about-the-project